# Using AspNetCore.SignalR with net462

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, .net-standard, .net-4.6.2

Apologies if this is a stupid question, I've been looking into this for hours and have gotten myself really confused by the different framework versions and by the current state of SignalR.

I've got an asp.net core 1.1 web application (.NET Framework) currently targetting net462, and I wish to add websocket functionality to this using SignalR. I've tried adding the MyGet feed (https://dotnet.myget.org/F/aspnetcore-master/api/v3/index.json) but can't add `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR`, even though this seems to be the recommended course of action. I wondered if this was because of an incompatibility between SignalR and net462, but SignalR targets netstandard1.3 which as far as I can tell should be compatible with net462.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: what errors do you get?

Comment: Sorry it wasn't clear. The package isn't listed in the nuget search results, even with the myget feed added. I guessed this was because of the differing framework types, but I don't know if it's something else? Whatever it is, I'm at step 0 currently - I've not even been able to get an error yet because I can't find a package to add!

Comment: I only noticed now - you added the feed for the master branch. You need this feed: `<add key="AspNetCore" value="https://dotnet.myget.org/F/aspnetcore-ci-dev/api/v3/index.json" />`

Comment: Cheers, I corrected the feed and tried again but it's still not finding the package, only the Gray.Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Server package which I assume (from the Gray prefix) isn't correct? I included pre-release just in case too but it still didn't show

Comment: Just noticed I forgot to say in the question, it's an ASP.NET Core 1.1 app in case that makes a difference?

Comment: Ah ok I found it! I was using the nuget gui and didn't notice there's a dropdown to select which feed to use - I assumed it just searched them all

Answer (score 1):

I made two silly mistakes here, posting just in case it helps anyone else:

1. The correct feed url was: https://dotnet.myget.org/F/aspnetcore-ci-dev/api/v3/index.json
2. I didn't notice there was a 'Package source' dropdown

Comment: I don't see signlarR in the json file